# Slack API: Retrieve information about slack command

Tags: c#, .net, slack

I am not managing to get information about a slack command in my .NET Core project. I registered the command on the slack websites as /joinbot and there is a website looking like this which I put in as the URL: https://somewebsites.azurewebsites.net/Slack/joinbot

The code from the API controller looks like this:

```
namespace SlackAPI.Controllers {
    [ApiController]
    public class SlackController : ControllerBase {
        private readonly ISlackRequestHandler _requestHandler;
        private readonly SlackEndpointConfiguration _endpointConfig;
        private readonly ISlackApiClient _slack;
        private readonly ILogger<SlackController> _logger;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public SlackController(ISlackRequestHandler requestHandler, SlackEndpointConfiguration endpointConfig, ISlackApiClient slack, ILogger<SlackController> loggerIConfiguration configuration) {
            _requestHandler = requestHandler;
            _endpointConfig = endpointConfig;
            _slack = slack;
            _logger = logger;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [Route("[Controller]/joinbot")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Joinbot([FromBody] SlashCommandPayloadDto payload) {
            await _slack.Chat.PostMessage(new SlackNet.WebApi.Message() { Text = $"{payload.text} {payload.response_url} {payload.command} {payload.user_name}", Channel = _configuration.GetValue<string>("Slack:ChannelToSend")}, null);

            return Ok();
        }

        
    }
}

public class SlashCommandPayloadDto {
    public string? token { get; set; }
    public string? team_id { get; set; }
    public string? team_domain { get; set; }
    public string? enterprise_id { get; set; }
    public string? enterprise_name { get; set; }
    public string? channel_id { get; set; }
    public string? channel_name { get; set; }
    public string? user_id { get; set; }
    public string? user_name { get; set; }
    public string? command { get; set; }
    public string? text { get; set; }
    public string? response_url { get; set; }
    public string? trigger_id { get; set; }
}
```

All other functions in the API controller work fine (I just deleted them here to make simple), swagger tells me that that specific URL exists and I can run it.

However, when I send /joinbot to my bot, I receive the message:

> "/joinbot failed with the error “dispatch_failed”"

Does anybody see an obvious reason why that does not work?